# How to Decode JSON in Swift 4?

Tags: json, swift, codable

How to decode following json using Swift 4?

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 22,
        "packageId": 5,
        "Package": {
            "id": 5,
            "color": "blue"
        }
    },
    "error": false,
    "message": "Successfully Fetched"
}
```

I have tried it using following:

```
struct Root: Codable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case packageId = "packageId"
        case package = "Package"
    }

    var package : Package
    var id : Int
    var packageId : Int
}

struct Package : Codable {
    var id : Int
    var color : String
}
```

It is giving me following error:

> keyNotFound(LocalNotificationsAlert.Root.CodingKeys.id,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No
>   value associated with key id (\"id\").", underlyingError: nil))

Please help me in fixing this, Thank you.

Comment: have a look of this Link https://grokswift.com/json-swift-4/

Comment: I did but I could not fix this yet. I have tried various ways

Comment: If there is a server error and `error` is `true`, will `data`, and its associated dictionary, be present? This will dictate whether that property must be optional or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Root** object is not the dictionary with `id`, `packageId` and `package` keys, the `Root` object is the outer dictionary with keys `data`, `error`, `message`.

So you need 3 structs

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let data : PackageData? // If `error` is true `data` might be missing
    let error : Bool
    let message : String
}

struct PackageData: Codable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case package = "Package"
        case id, packageId
    }

    let package : Package
    let id : Int
    let packageId : Int
}

struct Package : Codable {
    let id : Int
    let color : String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to custom decode the response, you would need to provide the struct for the entire json response.

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let data: Root
    let error: Bool
    let message: String
}
```