# Decode Custom Json with Decodable

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I have this Json:

```
{   "first": {
    "house": [
      "small"
    ]

  },   "second": {
    "house": [
      "small"
    ]   },   "third": {
    "car": [
      "fast",
      "economic"
    ]   },   "fourth": {
    "car": [
      "fast",
      "economic"
    ]   },   "fifth": {
    "car": [
      "fast",
      "economic"
    ],
    "ice": [
      "round",
      "tasty"
    ],
    "tree": [
      "big",
      "small"
    ]   } }
```

I tried to set up a structure with Decodable but I do not get it to work:

```
struct secondLayer: Codable {
    let exchange:  [String: [String]]
}

struct decodeJson: Codable {
    let symbol: [String: [secondLayer]]

    static func decode(jsonString: String) -    [decodeJson] {
        var output = [decodeJson]()
        let decode = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let json = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
            output = try! decode.decode([decodeJson].self, from: json!)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return output
    }
}
```

I get this Error:

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>,
Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription:
"Expected to decode Array<Any    but found a dictionary instead.",
underlyingError: nil)): file
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.74.1/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift,
line 181
```

I tried some modification but I do not get it to work.

Comment: This may be help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161748/how-to-decode-json-in-swift-4#48162199

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message

> "Expected to decode `Array<Any>` but found a dictionary instead."

is very clear. You want to decode an array (`[decodeJson]`) but the root object is a dictionary (starting with `{`)

Your code cannot work anyway. There are no keys `exchange` and `symbol` in the JSON.

Basically there are two ways to decode that JSON:

If all keys are **dynamic** you cannot decode the JSON to structs. You have to decode it to `[String:[String:[String]]]`. In this case `Codable` has no benefit over traditional `JSONSerialization`.

```
struct DecodeJson: Codable {

    static func decode(jsonString: String) -> [String:[String:[String]]] {
        var output = [String:[String:[String]]]()
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let json = Data(jsonString.utf8)
            output = try decoder.decode([String:[String:[String]]].self, from: json)
            print(output)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return output
    }
}
```

Or if the ordinal keys `first`, `second` etc are **static** use an umbrella struct

```
struct Root : Codable {

    let first : [String:[String]]
    let second : [String:[String]]
    let third : [String:[String]]
    let fourth : [String:[String]]
    let fifth : [String:[String]]
}


struct DecodeJson {

    static func decode(jsonString: String) -> Root? {

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let json = Data(jsonString.utf8)
            let output = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: json)
            return output
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can decode `house`, `car` etc into a struct but this requires a custom initializer for each struct because you have to decode a single array manually with `unkeyedContainer`